# Ruby/Rails nested hash myhash["key1"]["childkey"] - NoMethodError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash, ruby-on-rails-3.1

Hey guys so I'm trying to construct some json based on a form submission. My json needs to be something like this (truncated for simplicity):

```
{"id":0,"creditCard":{"address":{"state":"AZ"}}}
```

Basically I'm trying to do it like this:

```
json_hash = Hash.new
json_hash["id"] = 0
json_hash["creditCard"]["address"]["state"] = "test"
json_hash.to_json
```

But its throwing this errror:

```
You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!
You might have expected an instance of Array.
The error occurred while evaluating nil.[]
```

At the 3rd line in the example given (the deeply nested thing). Do ruby hashes work like this? Or are there extra steps I need to take?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because at the third line you're evaluating a `json_hash['creditCard']` which is `nil`, then it has no method `[]`.

You can build an hash like that using

```
json_hash = { "id" => 0,"creditCard" => { "address" => {"state" => "AZ"}}}
```

and it has the given format.

Thats a short syntax, to specify the fact that what you want in `json_hash` it's **NOT** a single hash. It is an hash which has the value 0 in its `"id"` key, then in its `"creditCard"` it stores **another** hash which contains **another** hash (i.e. `{"state" => "AZ"}`) in its `"address"` key.

Look at this pry transcript:

```
pry(main)> json_hash = { "id" => 0,"creditCard" => { "address" => {"state" => "AZ"}}}
=> {"id"=>0, "creditCard"=>{"address"=>{"state"=>"AZ"}}}
pry(main)> json_hash.object_id
=> 2175368520
pry(main)> json_hash['creditCard'].object_id
=> 2175368560
pry(main)> json_hash['creditCard']['address'].object_id
=> 2175368600
```

all these values have different `object_id` so they are not the same thing, neither property of the same thing.